# When parsing does not work "for"

Tags: json, swift

When parsing does not work "for"

In what there can be an error?

Earlier this code worked with such JSON, but when I changed JSON "for" stopped working
[image]

```
    do{
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : Any]

            if let main = json["LIBRARY"] as? [[String : Any]]{

                for data in main {
                    var info = Modal()
                    info.name = data["NAME"] as? String
                    info.id = data["ID"] as? String
                    info.ImageViewURL = data["PICTURE"] as! String
                    print(info.id)

                    if let filesArray = data["FILES"] as? [[String : Any]] {
                        for file in filesArray {
                            var info = Modal()
                            info.name = file["NAME"] as? String
                            info.audioUrl = file["SRC"] as? String

                            print(info.name! as Any)
                            print(info.audioUrl! as Any, "\n")

                            self.modals.append(info)
                        }

                    }

                    print(info.name)

                    self.modals.append(info)

                }
            }

        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
```

Here is my current JSON

[image]

Comment: In the second JSON, `json["LIBRARY"]` is not an array of dictionaries. It's a dict. So you can't do `as? [[String : Any]]`. It should be `as? [String : Any]`.

Comment: @Larme So it outputs an error     info.name = data["NAME"] as? String   Type '(key: String, value: Any)' has no subscript members

Comment: @programmer I was pointing the first issue. You misinterpreted the format of your JSON. In the posted code, your issue wasn't even passing the for loop, I guess that if you added a `print()` after the `if let` of `json["LIBRARY"]` it wouldn't even be printed. So since the structure changed, that would have mean that the rest too. You can't parse a dictionary the exact same way as an array. The rest was up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Library key contains dictionary not array and each key of dictionary also contains value as dictioanry, So make it this way.

```
if let main = json["LIBRARY"] as? [String:[String : Any]]{
    //Now loop though the dictionary
    for (_, data) in main {
        //Now access data dictionary same way you are accessing previously
        var info = Modal()
        info.name = data["NAME"] as? String
        info.id = data["ID"] as? String
        info.ImageViewURL = data["PICTURE"] as! String
        print(info.id)

        if let filesArray = data["FILES"] as? [[String : Any]] {
            for file in filesArray {
                var info = Modal()
                info.name = file["NAME"] as? String
                info.audioUrl = file["SRC"] as? String
                print(info.name! as Any)
                print(info.audioUrl! as Any, "\n")
                self.modals.append(info)
            }
        }
        print(info.name)
        self.modals.append(info)
    }
}
```

**Note:** From your `JSON` response it looks like that `ID` is `Number` not `String` if this `info.id = data["ID"] as? String` work then its sure number cast it to `Int`.

Comment: @programmer Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

you have a another tag after "LIBRARY" which is "47234", you need to first parse data for this tag, then you can apply this code

```
 for data in main {
                var info = Modal()
                info.name = data["NAME"] as? String
                info.id = data["ID"] as? String
                info.ImageViewURL = data["PICTURE"] as! String
                print(info.id)

                if let filesArray = data["FILES"] as? [[String : Any]] {
                    for file in filesArray {
                        var info = Modal()
                        info.name = file["NAME"] as? String
                        info.audioUrl = file["SRC"] as? String

                        print(info.name! as Any)
                        print(info.audioUrl! as Any, "\n")

                        self.modals.append(info)
                    }

                }

                print(info.name)

                self.modals.append(info)

            }
        }
```